# Javascript split text from file to array with Regex based on DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split

I am trying to split an imported text file into an array based on the fact each line starts with a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I have tried using regex to achieve this:

```
flist = f.split(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/)
```

with `f` being the string to split. However the code runs and produces an array saved to `flist` and when `console.log(flist)` is run it only has one element and has not been split up.

**edit:**

Full code:

```
const fs = require("fs")

f = fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8")
let flist = f.split(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/g)
console.log(flist)
```

example file.txt:

```
18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person2: message
18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person1: Yes
18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person2: That's good then
18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person1: message line 1
 message line 2
18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person2: text
18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person2: But nvm
18/07/2018, 18:06 - Person1: text
```

So the issue with splitting with new line is that a new line doesn't mean a new message however i want my array to be each new message so therefore need each new element to start with DD/MM/YYYY an am searching to split with that with regex however it is not splitting/finding a match.

Comment: Something like `let [_, day, month, year] = f.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);`?

Comment: I don't think so becuase i would like to split it into a single list where each element is a message which starts with the dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: `let res = f.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/).slice(1); `? Note `.split(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/).filter(Boolean)` works, too.

Comment: I get an error with the first one and the second one still isnt working
¬let res = f.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/).slice(1);
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at Object.<anonymous>....

Comment: Can't you just split per line? I don't see it as a significant timeloss. Otherwise wouldn't `/g` be missing?

Comment: I can't split per line becuase not every line is a new message therefore new element in my array

Comment: Also `/g` doesn't fix it

Comment: I do not quite understand what the scenario looks like. You have lines that you test against the regex, right? And there can be matching lines and those lines that do not match. Right? Then, iterate over the lines and use `var flist = ((m = f.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/)) ? m.slice(1) : [])`

Comment: Hi check the text after **edit:** on the main body

Comment: So, you want to split a whole file into substrings starting with datetimes? `f.split(/(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/m).filter(Boolean)`? See https://regex101.com/r/c5mglk/1

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want and your code there works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split with

```
var flist = f.split(/(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/m).filter(Boolean)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5mglk/1)

The `(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})` pattern matches a location that is right at the start of a line (`m` modifier makes `^` match start of a line) that is followed with 1 or 2 digits, `/`, 1 or 2 digits, `/` and 4 digits. The `.filter(Boolean)` part will remove empty items.

JS demo:

```js
var f = "18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person2: message\n18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person1: Yes\n18/07/2018, 18:04 - Person2: That's good then\n18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person1: message \nine 1\n message line 2\n18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person2: text\n18/07/2018, 18:05 - Person2: \nut nvm\n18/07/2018, 18:06 - Person1: text";
var flist = f.split(/(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/m).filter(Boolean);
console.log(flist);
```